# Serial Port not recognized by Arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, mac-os

I’m attempting to connect with a Adafruit Huzzah Feather ESP8266 board. I’m running a 2018 mbp with Mojave. I loaded the Silabs driver (CP210) to connect with the onboard UART on Huzzah board. I got the Arduino IDE 1.8.8 installed and loaded the 2.5.0 ESP8266 library (I also tried library 2.4.2).

The serial port appears  in the IDE (SLAB_USBtoUART). It also appears when I run the /dev/tty.* command and in About this Mac. From the IDE when I try to Get Board Info. Nothing. I get the message “Native serial port, can’t obtain info”. Everything seems good, except nothing from the IDE. I pulled up CoolTerm, set it the port and hit the reset on the Huzzah. I see data after hitting reset.

I run the Huzzah board from a powered USB hub through one of the USB-C ports. Tried different combinations, no luck.

I have a very old WIn7 machine, loaded everything like on my mbp, there I can get board info. I would run the IDE on it, except the machine is sooo slow. I would very much like to get it working on my mac. It seems so close, but no cigar.

Comment: did you try to upload to the board? the "Get Board Info" works only with some Arduinos

Comment: Yes, on the win7 machine I was able to upload to the board.

Comment: and on Mac? do you have same error message? turn on verbose mode in Preferences.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks to @Juraj for suggesting turning on verbose mode. Thanks. Not getting Board Info from the IDE, I figured the port wasn't working. Ignoring the Board Info problem, I went to compile and upload a simple program. Without verbose mode on, it looked like it wasn't connecting up. In reality it was a problem with the esp8266 libraries. After fixing that issue all is good.

Answer (score -1):

Download usb port driver from the link below
http://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/CH341SER_EXE.html

Comment: Adafruit Huzzah Feather ESP826 has CP2104 as USB chip, not CH340